# Copying table from excel in active document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have an open word document and am trying to copy a table from an excel file using VBA. The code is written in word doc. This is because in future I intend to put a button in the word document, which when pressed should pull in table from a specified excel. My code is as follows:

```
Sub GetTable()

    Dim oXL As Excel.Application
    Dim wb1 As Excel.Workbook
    Dim WorkbookToWorkOn As String
    Dim ExcelWasNotRunning As Boolean

    On Error Resume Next
    Set oXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    If Err Then
       ExcelWasNotRunning = True
       Set oXL = New Excel.Application
    End If


    Set wb1 = oXL.Workbooks.Open("*.xlsx")

    oXL.Visible = True
    wb1.Sheets("**").Range("N3:AB49").Copy
    Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseStart
    'Selection.Paste
    Selection.PasteExcelTable False, False, False
    oXL.Quit
    Set oXL = Nothing

End Sub
```

The code just pastes whatever I had copied in recent time and not the data from the table

Comment: Works fine for me. Is it possible the Excel workbook is already open an in edit mode, or something, so that the code isn't executing correctly?

Comment: precisely so. Have got the code to work.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'Change to your Excel file path
Set wb1 = objExcel.workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Lee Li Fong\Desktop\Website\Spreadsheets For Sales\Copy Excel Table to Word\template Specification.xlsm")
objExcel.Visible = True
wb1.sheets("Specification").Range("A6:F12").Copy    'Change to your sheet name & range
Selection.Collapse direction:=wdCollapseStart
Selection.Paste

objExcel.Quit
Set objExcel = Nothing
```

Comment: I have provided the full code. This is not working. Kindly suggest